# sysctl: malformed setting "net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports="

Tags: linux, sysctl

I'm trying to assign an empty string to a system setting, but it fails:

```
[root@wc8rh7 ~]# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports="50000"
net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports = 50000
[root@wc8rh7 ~]# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports=""
sysctl: malformed setting "net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports="
```

Using procfs directly succeeds:

```
[root@wc8rh7 ~]# echo >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_reserved_ports
[root@wc8rh7 ~]# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports
net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports =
```

Comment: Looks like the input validation is tripping over itself. Report the issue at https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268210/sysctl-malformed-setting-net-ipv4-ip-local-reserved-ports#comment464756_268210), this does look like a bug. Writing directly to `procfs` is an obvious workaround. If you need to use the `sysctl` utility, another workaround is to add a newline:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports="
"
```

A trailing newline has no effect on most if not all sysctl settings.